# Trouble installing third-party modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working through Automate The Boring Stuff With Python book, but I ran into issues when trying to install the third-party modules required for some of the exercises.

I'm following the instructions provided on the books [Appendix A](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/appendixa/)

When trying to install imapclient module I get the following error message:

```
Command
"/home/peksi/Documents/python3/projects/environments/automation/bin/python3
-u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cnal9syj/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record /tmp/pip-0oxau5ge-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/peksi/Documents/python3/projects/environments/automation/include/site/python3.5/cryptography"
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cnal9syj/cryptography/
```

Rest of the  modules installed without any problems.

What should I do to successfully install the imapclient module?

Edit: In case it helps the full terminal output is shown [here](http://pastebin.com/StaHT6Ee)

Comment: Which package were you trying to install?

Comment: Use code formatting for error messages, not quote formatting. They're not quite code, but quote-formatting them isn't readable and even loses information about spacing and line breaks.

Comment: @Pekka-Pousi Just to clarify, you got that error message after running the command "sudo pip3 install imapclient" as per the instructions in Appendix A? (I'm assuming you are on linux based on the path in the command: '/home/peksi/...')

Comment: @JackManey I was trying to install IMAPClient module.

Comment: @ChrisLarson Yeah I'm on linux(ElementaryOS) and used "sudo pip3 install imapclient" command.

Comment: @PekkaPousi Hope you don't mind, but I added a somewhat parsed version of your error message at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Ha! Nailed it! (Knock on wood.) Reading the full log reveals the _real_ problem. See my suggested answer, and let us know if that solves the problem. After installing those headers, try a straight "sudo pip3 install cryptography" first, then run the imapclient install again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure, on linux, that all the correct development headers are installed before `cryptography` will install. In your case, going by the full terminal output, you're missing the openssl headers.

Note that you'll also need libffi and it's headers. Might as well install that too while you're at it:

If you're on a Debian/Ubuntu distribution:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev libffi-dev
```

Otherwise, use whatever package management your distribution uses.

Comment: Excellent! So glad to hear it!